# How do I raise a review from intellij 2017 using the gerrit plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, gerrit

I see that the [plugin documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7272-gerrit) mentions "Publish and delete draft changes" as one of the features. I have installed the plugin and have configured it to work with my corporate gerrit server and I am able to view all changes which have already been raised for review on the server.

However, I am yet to figure out how do I commit new changes locally and raise a review for those using the gerrit plugin from my intelliJ 2017.2.6. I tried Googling around and I did see people mentioning about a "push dialog box" that they were trying to configure but I don't see that option available for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the Gerrit plugin installed on PyCharm, often the behaviour of the plugins is quite similar across several JetBrains products, so this *might* be applicable to IntelliJ as well.

In my case the dialog box for the `VCS->GIT->Push` menu sequence (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for Mac) was modified by the plugin to look similar to the one displayed in the 2nd screenshot displayed at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7272-gerrit:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Tried and saw it works exactly as I want it to. Thanks!